# Possible way of having multiple Gutenberg instances for a page?

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, block-editor

I'm trying to create a system in which the Admin of the wordpress site can create different "versions" of a same page depending on the custom user roles we create for certain users. There's a fairly good amount of pages that need this feature so my idea is to create a plugin that, for each page created on the backend, can have multiple instances of the gutenberg editor (one per user role) that the page shows different content based on the user role that a certain user has when logged in.

Is there any way I can have some sort of toggle that lets the Admin switch between multiple instances of the Gutenberg editor for any given page?

Any ideas as to where to start looking are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why you would want to do this. Are you trying to limit which blocks the user can use on which pages? Are you trying to allow the users to duplicate a page layout?

Comment: Basically the idea is to have pages (for example /foo) have a different set of content and layout alltogether based on the user Role . Page /foo has blocks A, B and C, each with specific content, if user with role X hits that url. If user with role Y hits /foo they would see blocks D, E and B, so essentially different content for that user role. And we want to update the content periodically.